# Numpy savetxt not appending when using with open

Tags: python, numpy

I want to use the more concise "with open(...)..." syntax to append to a file using numpy savetxt; however it just overwrites instead of appending.  I can append correctly when using separate, "f = open(...)" syntax.  I'm using Spyder 5.1.5 with Python 3.8. Code:

```
import numpy as np
Array = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

this will append correctly:

```
f = open('testfile.o','a', encoding="utf-8")
np.savetxt(f,Array, fmt='%4.2f\n')
f.close()
```

this will overwrite whatever was previously in `testfile.o`

```
with open('testfile.o', 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    np.savetxt('testfile.o', Array, fmt='%4.2f\n')
```

What am I missing here?  Shouldn't these two code blocks function the same?

Comment: In the second example, f is not used. You use the file name instead

Comment: ah...thanks.  That was a silly mistake on my part.